# How do you punctuate "So basically" when it appears at the beginning of the sentence?

Tags: punctuation, commas, writing-style, discourse-markers

How do you punctuate "So basically" when it appears at the beginning of the sentence?

I see four possibilities:

- So, basically, we had to pay the fine.
- So basically we had to pay the fine.
- So, basically we had to pay the fine.
- So basically, we had to pay the fine.

Comment: Please provide the rest of the sentence

Comment: Punctuate it however you like - it's a ***stylistic choice***. You can have no commas, one, or two. You could even replace at least the first one (*maybe* the second) with a period or a dash if you want. Even to the extent that "style guides" might address the punctuation of "sentence adverb clauses" like this, your particular example is pretty "casual, slangy", so their advice doesn't necessarily apply to your exact context.

Comment: "So, basically, we had to pay the fine."  When an adverbial modifier appears in advance of the subject-verb, grammar calls for it to be separated off with commas.  When a coordinating subjunctive like "so" is used to introduce a coordinate cause, though, the comma between "so" and an introductory modifier is eliminated (e.g., "We got all the fees waived, so, basically, we had to pay the fine.").  However, when that coordinate clause appears as a whole new sentence, grammar calls for that comma to remain.

Comment: I think _So essentially, ..._ is less garden-pathy than _So basically [...]_ and therefore I'd use this.

Comment: Don’t write it. That will solve your problem. It’s an awful misuse of the idea of basic. Whatever you mean (and it is not clear without more context) say it — “To cut a long story short”, “In sum”, “In effect”, “At the end of the day”, “What it amounted to”, “In essence”, “The outcome was”…

Comment: This is not written English. This is strictly spoken. You can't hear punctuation anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm not too late (like, 3 years after), but the correct punctuation would be the first one :)

The second one is absolutely a phone text message.
The third one is the second-best option, but still misses a comma; though, no one will get confused.
The fourth one means: "SO (much?) basically, blah blah"
...which really means nothing.

Comment: Can you tell us *why* you think so?

Comment: Hello, pal. There has already been a question discussing the correctness of zero punctuation around short parentheticals where no complications arise. At least some style advisors seem quite happy with the practice. // Speaking of commas, I'd say the one after 'though' in your answer is unusual to non-standard.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'll go with that, either two commas or none. One comma in either position is incorrect in my opinion.

Answer (score -3):

I would say 1 or 4.  I believe that 1 is probably  more correct, but 4 is more in line with how the sentence is actually spoken.